# Euler Characteristic Equation on polyhedron with 1 and 2 vertices?

Tags: general-topology

Does it make sense to talk about Euler Characteristic Equation on polyhedron with 1 and 2 vertices? for 1 vertex case, what I count is 1 vertex, 0 edge and 0 face(although I read somewhere that it should have 1 face, which I don't quite understand). For 2 vertices case, I count 2 vertices, 1 edge and also 0 face. Can someone explain to me what I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes to sense to talk about Euler characteristics on any finite CW complex (that is, any object you can make by attaching vertices, edges, faces, and so on). Yo can calculate it by summing the number of odd-dimensional cells and subtracting the number of even-dimensional cells. (For instance, for surfaces, V+F-E)

So, you're right. A vertex has Euler characteristic 1(=1-0+0), and a line segment the same, 1(=2-1+0).

However, Euler's polyhedron formula only holds for polyhedrons (and in general any closed oriented surfaces with genus 0), and you cannnot apply the formula to a vertex or a line segment.